# .htaccess rewrite to index.php infinite loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, infinite-loop

I am building a clean url system using .htaccess and php.
The main idea is to rewrite everything to index.php and to split the url to segments separated by /.
It works but when I upload it to web server I get an infinite loop error.

My .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If I get things correctly - the problem is that it redirects index.php to itself but it shouldn't because I have index.php file that handles everything and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which should prevent that rewrite.

Could you please help me with this .htaccess - I want it to rewrite everything to index.php and to be as portable as it can be, so I can use it in:

www.mysite.com
www.myothersite.com

or even
www.mysite.com/new/

I also want to redirect something like www.mysite.com/articles/2 to index.php as well as www.mysite.com/articles/it/2 or even www.mysite.com/articles/it/search/searchterm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code taken from [Drupal](http://drupal.org)'s .htaccess which uses the "clean urls" approach you are trying to achieve.

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In this case, it appends the clean URL as the "q" querystring parameter. So then your script can detect what content to deliver based on `$_GET['q']`.

And here's another approach, this one from [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This one specifically looks for requests to `index.php` and filters them out before doing the redirection.

Comment: The second (Wordpress) didn't work - gives me infinite loop again - obviosly I am doing something wrong. However the Drupal's approach worked without the loop error. THANK YOU! I am curious though - where is this error comming from???

Comment: It's hard to say. Maybe another script on your server is creating the redirect?

Comment: If my original answer was the solution to your problem, please mark it as "accepted". Take the [StackOverflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to do this. Thanks.